# conditonal / segmented regression

Tags: regression

I have a general question regarding the methodology of "conditional" or "segmented" regression. I have a data set of values (x,y) and I am interested in defining a model for y as a function of x at *different ranges* of values. I have seen reference to piecewise / segmented regression but I was not thinking that it's important that the regression lines are joined at any knot points, etc.

Instead I was planning on simply running separate OLS (y~x) using pairs of data using the y's corresponding to the filtered x's. i was hoping to get some pointers on whether this approach had any obvious flaws or perhaps if there was a more robust method.

Comment: It depends on (1) whether those ranges of values are determined independently of the data and (2) whether anything else in addition to their intercept and slope can vary from one segment to the next.  Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

The main possible flaw is what you already state:

> I was not thinking that it's important that the regression lines are
>   joined at any knot points

This is usually quite important. Jumps in the relationship between two continuous variables are not likely to be realistic. There may be such cases, but they will be very specific. Your approach is equivalent to categorizing a continuous independent variable. In *Regression Modelling Strategies* Frank Harrell lists 11 problems with this. I wrote a [post showing what can go wrong](https://medium.com/@peterflom/what-happens-when-we-categorize-an-independent-variable-in-regression-77d4c5862b6c).

Please tell us what your dependent and independent variables are and why you think that jumps in the line are OK.